# How to express loglikelihood in terms of other loglikelihood?

Tags: log-likelihood

I am trying to find out how to decompose conditional loglikelihood of a function to a conditional loglikelihood of an argument plus some reminder terms.

I.e. shortly:
$$\mathcal{L}_E(\hat{E};\sigma) = \mathcal{L}_A(F^{-1}(\hat{E});\sigma) + \ldots$$
where $E=F({A})$, i.e. $F$ - my function, $A$ - my argument.

> Real decomposition looks like this: $$
>  \mathcal{L}_E(\hat{E_1},\ldots,\hat{E_N};\sigma) =
>  \mathcal{L}_A(F^{-1}(\hat{E_1}),\dots,F^{-1}(\hat{E_N});\sigma) -
>  \sum^{N}_{i=1}\log \left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}\right]
>  ((F^{-1}(E,\sigma)) $$

But for now, I can see how author obtained it. It reminds me kind of Taylor expansion:
$$E = F(A) + \int F(A)'dA + \ldots$$
where $F(A)$ should be $ \mathcal{L}_A(F^{-1}(\hat{E_1}),\dots,F^{-1}(\hat{E_N});\sigma) $, $ F(A)' \approx \left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}\right] $ and $ A \approx ((F^{-1}(E,\sigma))$.

But this is of course very vaguely written, as: not $F(A)$ but $A$ should be $ \mathcal{L}_A(F^{-1}(\hat{E_1}),\dots,F^{-1}(\hat{E_N});\sigma)$ and I do not write the integral in second case. 
Moreover we see equal expression, not infinite sum...
Could somebody give a hint how to decompose it?

For simplification, I have been looking at case of just one conditional density function, but could not represent it so far.

**REFERENCE:** [problem appears on page 7 of these lecture notes](https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/09-10/finance/courses/hurdnotes2.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I overlooked the reference in the lecture notes. There is a paper of Duan, which I initially could not find in the web.

The idea turned out to be straightforward: transformation is done using Jacobian.